# Handwritten text dictionary

Tags: android, ios

I don't know if I am asking the right question even: Is there an Apple/Android app that allow non-native English speakers to draw a word and look up its meaning at the same time? I high value any suggestions/responses to my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Google Translate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.translate&hl=en) application can do this for you.  There is a squiggly line at the lower right of the window on startup that lets you draw there and get a translation or description.

I believe that the same application did that for iOS as well.  It can even use the camera to translate what it sees for you instead of writing it down and getting a translation if it is in front of you or in written material.